# Vault: How to tell response wrapped-token was already read

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, secret-key, hashicorp-vault

Im using Vault by HashiCorp to store my secrets, and as was advised in this [blog](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/vault-cubbyhole-principles.html): on target_application-startup I provide to a Response-Wrapped token via the ENV_PARAM to authenticate with vault.

Next,  the target_application tries to get the permanentToken but fails
due to 2 possible cases where I cant access Vault:

1. The token the target_application got is already expired.
2. The token was already read by somebody else so I cant read it now.

In both cases I get "permission denied" from vault.

How can I check that the 2nd case happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that works for me:
when creating a response-wrapped token you get:
 1.token creation time
 2. token's time to live
Adding these two and passing the result to the target-application helps you (in case of getting denial of token) determine  which of the 2 occurred.